# showing a function is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to show that $f: Z_4 \to Z_{12}$ given by $f( \overline{x} ) = [3x] $ is well defined.

I need to show that if $\overline{x} = \overline{y} $, then $f( \overline{x}) = f( \overline{y} )$. Can I just say by contradiction that $f( \overline{x} ) \neq f( \overline{y} ) $ so $[3x] \neq [3y] $ and so $[x] - [y] \neq 12 k \implies [x] - [y] \neq 0 $ mod 4  which implies $\overline{x} \neq \overline{y} $.

Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean contraposition?

Comment: It is correct except that you probably had a typo in $[x] - [y] \neq 12 k$. It should be $[3x] - [3y] \neq 12 k$